# Break NDSolve when condition is "almost" constant

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, conditional

I'm trying the solve a differential equation using NDSolve, starting at x=0.001.
I'd like the solver to stop when the function

```
CSq[x_]:=psi[x]^2*x^(2 l + 2) + psi[x - Pi/2]^2*(x - Pi/2)^(2 l + 2)
```

is "almost" constant, up to a specified tolerance value. My code so far is

```
tol = 10^-4;
xmin = 0.0001;
l=1;
V[x_] := -1/x Exp[-x];
eqn = {
   psi''[x] + 2 (l + 1) psi'[x]/x + psi[x] - V[x] psi[x] == 0,
   psi[xmin] == 1,
   psi'[xmin] == 0,
   CSq[x_] := 
    psi[x]^2*x^(2 l + 2) + psi[x - Pi/2]^2*(x - Pi/2)^(2 l + 2),
   WhenEvent[CSq1 - CSq[x] < tol, xmax = x, "StopIntegration"],
   CSq1=CSq[x]
   };
NDSolve[eqn, psi[x], {x, xmin, \[Infinity]}];
```

where i want the `WhenEvent` to trigger when to previous value of `psi` is close enough to the current value. This doesn't work, and leads me to the following questions:

1. In the error message, it says `Equation or list of equations expected instead of Null in the first argument`, so i guess that i can't define functions inside `NDSolve` like this. Is there some solution to this?
2. Even if i remove the function declaration and use `psi` directly everywhere, i still get error like the one above. I suspect that my last line in `eqn` is what bothers `NDSolve`. Is there any convenient way to access the previous value and compare it to the current, during the `NDSolve` operation?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: What is a typical value for `CSq1`?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Roughly `4.6`.

Comment: When `x<Pi/2`, how to calculate `psi[x]`?

Comment: @xzczd  Good question.  I worked around this issue by setting `CSq` to zero there.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can be solved by means of `DiscreteVariables`.

```
tol = 10^-3;
xmin = 10^-4;
l = 1;
V[x_] := -1/x Exp[-x];
eqn = {psi''[x] + 2 (l + 1) psi'[x]/x + psi[x] - V[x] psi[x] == 0,   
    psi[xmin] == 1, psi'[xmin] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[x, Pi/2], {tt = psi[x]^2*x^(2 l + 2), 
        If[Abs[tem[x] + tt - CSq[x]] < tol, "StopIntegration"], 
        CSq[x] -> tem[x] + tt, tem[x] -> tt}], CSq[xmin] == 0, tem[xmin] == 0};
s = Flatten@NDSolve[eqn, {psi[x], CSq[x]}, {x, xmin, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {CSq, tem];
```

Basically, `tem` stores old values of `psi[x]^2*x^(2 l + 2)`, and `CSq` stores old values of the corresonding quantity defined in the question, with new values computed when `x` is a multiple of `Pi/2`.  The computation stops when the absolute value of the change in `CSq` is less than `tol`.

Next, extract the `Plot` limits.  (The final number is the value of `x` at which the integration stopped.)

```
plotlim = Join[{x}, Flatten[CSq[x] /. s /. x -> "Domain"]]
(* {x, 0.0001, 61.2611} *)

Plot[CSq[x] /. s, plotlim, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[psi[x] /. s, plotlim, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The corresponding calculation for `tol = 10^-4` requires `WorkingPrecision -> 30` to obtain adequate accuracy from `NDSolve`, which then stops at `x == 179.070781254618214592370672859`.